# How to get a value inside a map that is inside a tuple

Tags: tuples, elixir

I have a tuple as a response for a function. It returns

```elixir
{:ok, %User{name: "John Doe", age: 21, code: "123456"}}
```

and I need the `code`. How do I access the map inside this tuple to get only the `code`?

Comment: Pretty sure you can do `{_, User%{code: code}} = data`

Comment: I think you meant: `{_, %User{code: code}} = data`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use the pattern matching

```elixir
{:ok, %User{code: code}} = {:ok, %User{name: "John Doe", age: 21, code: "123456"}}
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `elem(tup,1)` ([documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#elem/2)) to get the second element in the tuple, and [square brackets](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html) to get `code` from the `User` [struct](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html). e.g.

```
user = elem(tup,1)
code = user[:code]
```